# redshift SQL - Histogram With Equal Width Bins

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I currently have table like so:

| ID | Count Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 24 |
| 3 | 13 |
| 4 | 67 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 21 |
| ... | ... |

**Anyone know how to create a table that I can use to create a histogram with equal width bins going from min to max?**

End result would look something like this:

| Bin of Values | Count(of IDs) |
| --- | --- |
| min-5 | 3 |
| 6-10 | 20 |
| 11-15 | 5 |
| 16-20 | 2 |
| 21-25 | 35 |
| ... | ... |
| (max-5)-max | 1 |

I have used width_bucket in the past, but Redshift does not support the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` in Redshift. It's a bit more laborious than `width_bucket` but the results can be the same:

```
select
    case
        when val between 0 and 5
            then '0-5'
        when val between 5 and 10
            then '5-10'
        when val between 10 and 15
            then '10-15'
        when val between 15 and 20
            then '15-20'
        ...
        end,
    count(1)
from my_table
group by 1;
```